# Which light barding provides the best protection per ACP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor, animals

Which light armor for an animal companion provides the most protection for the least amount of ACP?

Comment: The sentence asking for what people “recommend” and for “which type of barding would work” is confusing: the first is asking for opinions, the second is asking for facts. Which did you mean to ask?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Now we see revealed a new problem: this is two questions, but it's one question post. We require one question per post, so that the answers can focus on one problem at a time. I've removed one of the questions in order to reopen this. Please feel free though to post the other question about whether a feat is needed for the T-Rex to wear light barding in its own question post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barding provides the same protection as armor of the same type, so:

- Padded/Quilted Cloth    **1AC+8 Max Dex/0ACP**
- Leather/Rosewood        **2AC+6 Max Dex/0ACP**
- Hide                    **3AC+4 Max Dex/1ACP (3-7 AC/P)**
- Studded Leather/Parade  **3AC+5 Max Dex/1ACP (3-8 AC/P)**
- Wooden                  **3AC+3 Max Dex/1ACP (3-6 AC/P)**
- Chain Shirt             **4AC+4 Max Dex/2ACP (2-4 AC/P)**

If you really want to reduce the ACP, you can purchase/make Masterwork Barding for 150g; this will reduce the ACP to 0 for all but Chain Shirts. From this data:

**Leather provides the most AC with no ACP** (non-masterwork)

**Studded Leather provides the best ratio of AC to ACP**, (with the added bonus of the highest Max Dex available)

It wasn't necessarily part of your question, but it's good information that's related: for things you would typically supply barding to, you do not need Armor Proficiency if your ACP is 0. **The only penalty for non-proficiency (above typical armor penalties) is that the ACP applies to attack checks.** If your ACP is 0, there is no additional penalty.

---

Of note:

Masterwork Armor increases the cost by 150g (ask your GM if this is increased by the unusual shape/size chart) and reduced the ACP of armor by 1. Any Light armor except Chain Shirt will have no ACP if it is Masterwork, making Studded Leather the definite best.

You can purchase a Mithral Chain Shirt for +1000g (again ask your GM if the cost is increased by the unusual shape/size chart) which will have 0 ACP, making it the best option.

One more option has come to my attention: Darkleaf Hide is Medium Armor with 0 ACP, 4 AC +6 Max Dex. So for an agile companion/mount, Darkleaf Hide is the greatest AC/ACP ratio assuming we can make ratios with a denominator of 0. It should cost about 1500g.

Comment: You’re leaving off special materials which can drastically change the answer here.

Comment: Technically the ratios for Padded and Leather are infinity, but I digress.

Comment: Which special materials? Adamantine provides an extra DR, but no AC bonus. Mithral makes medium armor behave as light armor in certain respects, but does not give the companion proficiency with medium armor.

Comment: @MarcusYoder Mithral reduces the ACP of metal armors by 3 and increases the max dex by 2. Chain Shirt's ACP becomes zero and the max dex becomes +6, so a +4 AC and a max of +10 total armor+dex, with no ACP.

Comment: Would a Mithril chain shirt be considered Light armor? What is the ACP on that and max dex bonus?

Comment: Between Mithral and Masterwork, any Light armor can have ACP 0, you just have to be willing to fork out a lot of money.

Comment: [Mithral](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral) costs 1000g, possibly increased/decreased by the table for [unusual/different sized creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/#TOC-Armor-for-Unusual-Creatures)

Comment: As an aside, if you have armor with no ACP, there is no reason to spend the Feat on proficiency with it. The only penalty for using armor you are not proficient with is "Nonproficient with Armor Worn: A character who wears armor and/or uses a shield with which he is not proficient takes the armor’s (and/or shield’s) armor check penalty on attack rolls as well as on all Dex– and Str-based ability and skill checks. The penalty for non-proficiency with armor stacks with the penalty for shields."

Comment: @Ifusaso it doesn't matter in this case, but there are other downsides to wearing armor you aren't proficient with, such as spell failure chance or class abilities (thought those generally aren't tied to proficiency, just armor category)

Comment: @WeirdFrog Your proficiency or lack thereof doesn't *alter* spell failure, unless you have a class feature (magus, bard, etc) or the feat that allows you to ignore it, a case that wouldn't be relying on this question.

Comment: @Ifusaso Adding mithral & masterwork to the answer would greatly improve it. Remember comments are temporary.